# OpenCV trying to use windows to show image throws exception

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, raspberry-pi

I´m trying to create named windows and show an image from them using OpenCV in c++. When I try it, I will get an error saying:

> The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows,
>   GTK+2.x or Cocoa support.  If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install
>   libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in
>   function 'cvNamedWindow'.

I´m on a raspberry pi using `Ubuntu MATE` and I didnt have this problem when I was testing on my laptop using `Ubuntu`. I have checked that all neccessary libraries are installed. So I run `cmake` again to recompile it, but it still doesn t work.

Is there something different I need to do for `Ubuntu MATE`?  Or is there something else I should try?

Comment: What are your CMake options to build `OpenCV`? Which `OpenCV` version do you use? How does your programm looks like? Please add some more information to this question otherwise nobody can help you.

Comment: I ran cmake without any options.  If its helpful I can add the output from the cmake to the question when I get home.  Also it shouldnt be an issue with my code as it works on another computer with the exact same code.